# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} na_{n+1}$ implies convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} na_n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)$ be an infinite sequence such that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} na_{n+1}$ converges. Is it true that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} na_n$ converges ?

**My attemt**: If $a_n>0$, for each $n$, then $0<a_{n+1}\leq na_{n+1}$, so $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n+1}$ converges. Hence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges. Now, since
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_n=a_1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_{n+1}+
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n
$$
it follows that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} na_n$ converges, as required. Can we drop the assumption that $a_n>0$?

Comment: I fixed that. Thanks

Comment: This is the other way, but the same idea works : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/588009/if-sum-limits-n-1-infty-na-n-converges-does-sum-limits-n-1-infty-na?rq=1

Comment: Thanks @TheSilverDoe

Comment: It probably fails when $a_n$ is allowed both signs.

Comment: There is a general theorem, due to Abel, that if the series $\sum a_n$ is convergent and $b_n$ is a convergent and monotonic sequence, then the series $\sum a_nb_n$ is convergent. Apply this for $b_n={n+1\over n}$ and $a_n:= na_{n+1}$